# Faster %in% operator

Tags: r, match

The [fastmatch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastmatch/index.html) package implements a much faster version of `match` for repeated matches (e.g. in a loop):

```
set.seed(1)
library(fastmatch)
table <- 1L:100000L
x <- sample(table, 10000, replace=TRUE)
system.time(for(i in 1:100) a <-  match(x, table))
system.time(for(i in 1:100) b <- fmatch(x, table))
identical(a, b)
```

Is there a similar implementation for `%in%` I could use to speed up repeated lookups?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Look at the definition of `%in%`:

```
R> `%in%`
function (x, table) 
match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
<bytecode: 0x1fab7a8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

It's easy to write your own `%fin%` function:

```
`%fin%` <- function(x, table) {
  stopifnot(require(fastmatch))
  fmatch(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
}
system.time(for(i in 1:100) a <- x %in% table)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.780   0.000   1.782 
system.time(for(i in 1:100) b <- x %fin% table)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.052   0.000   0.054
identical(a, b)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: but fastmatch it doesn't work if you match against NA, base match does.

Comment: Where is it?.  Is "https://github.com/s-u/fastmatch" the proper link?. It seems not to be updated since a long time ago.

Comment: I've been trying %fin% and fmatch with lapply to match on every column of a big data.frame or a data.table and can't notice much difference in speed.

Answer (score 4):

match is almost always better done by putting both vectors in dataframes and merging (see various joins from dplyr)

For example, something like this would give you all the info you need:

```
library(dplyr)

data = data_frame(data.ID = 1L:100000L,
                  data.extra = 1:2)

sample = 
  data %>% 
  sample_n(10000, replace=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(sample.ID = 1:n(),
         sample.extra = 3:4 )

# join table not strictly necessary in this case
# but necessary in many-to-many matches
data__sample = inner_join(data, sample)

#check whether a data.ID made it into sample
data__sample %>% filter(data.ID == 1)
```

or left_join, right_join, full_join, semi_join, anti_join, depending on what info is most useful to you

Comment: Would you mind explaining this (preferably with an example included)? At this moment your "answer" is more a comment than a real answer.