# Efficiently finding all matches of vector in lookup table, with repeats

Tags: r

I want to find indices of all matches of a vector `x` in another lookup vector `table`.

```
table = rep(1:5, each=3)
x = c(2, 5, 2, 6)
```

Standard base R methods don't quite give me what I want.  For example using `which(table %in% x)` we only get the matching indices once, even though `2` appears twice in `x`

```
which(table %in% x)
# [1]  4  5  6 13 14 15
```

On the other hand, `match` returns values for every occurrence of x that has a match, but only returns the first index in the lookup table.

```
match(x, table)
# [1]  4 13  4 NA
```

What I want is a function that returns the indices for "all x and all y".  I.e. it should return the following desired result:

```
mymatch(x, table)
# c(4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 4, 5, 6)
```

We can, of course, do this with a loop in R:

```
mymatch = function(x, table) {
  matches = sapply(x, \(xx) which(table %in% xx)) 
  unlist(matches)
}

mymatch(x, table)
# [1]  4  5  6 13 14 15  4  5  6
```

But this is horribly slow on larger data (I need to do this operation many times on big data)

```
table = rep(1:1e5, each=10)
x = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
system.time(mymatch(x, table))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 3.279   2.881   6.157
```

This is very slow if we compare it to e.g. `which %in%`:

```
system.time(which(table %in% x))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.003   0.004   0.008
```

Hoping there is a fast way to do this in R?  Otherwise, maybe RCpp is the way to go.

Comment: I asked a similar questions some time back: [Most efficient way to determine if element exists in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33453141/4408538)

Comment: When I run `mymatch` on the larger sample data, I get a 10x1000 matrix, is that the desired output structure?

Comment: @JonSpring - no it was not intended.  Well spotted.  The desired output format is a simple vector.

Comment: Is table always asorted array of 1:n? with m repetitions or is it a random vector

Comment: @Onyambu No, table is not necessarily 1:n. In my current use case, it's ok to assume it is sorted, although more general solutions are also of interest.

Comment: Are the values being matched always going to be integers?

Comment: Also, when running it multiple times, are you reusing the same table with different vectors? If so, almost certainly can process it into an intermediate object to remove a lot of the duplicate effort

Comment: @anjama yes integers, and yes the table remains fixed between iterations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another way is to use `split`:

```
unlist(split(seq(table), table)[as.character(x)],use.names = FALSE)
[1]  4  5  6 13 14 15  4  5  6
```

---

Edit:

Note that if `table` is sorted, then you could use `rle + sequence`:

```
faster <- function(x, table){
  a <- rle(table)
  n <- length(a$lengths)
  idx <- match(x, a$values, 0)
  sequence(a$lengths[idx], cumsum(c(1,a$lengths[-n]))[idx])
}

set.seed(42)
table = rep(1:1e5, each=10)
x = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
bench::mark(
   faster(x, table),
   #mymatch(x, table) |> as.vector(),
   join_match(x, table),
   #unlist(split(seq(table), table)[as.character(x)],use.names = FALSE),
   check = TRUE
 )


# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression     min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 faster(x,…  54.4ms  252ms      3.97    54.9MB     1.99     2     1      503ms <int>  <Rprofmem>
2 join_matc… 127.7ms  254ms      3.93    88.8MB     5.90     2     3      508ms <int>  <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

---

The function works as long as table is sorted. Not necessarily from 1:n.

```
table = c(rep(1:5, each=3), 7,7,7,7,10,10)
x = c(10, 2, 5,7, 2, 6)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   faster(x, table),
   #mymatch(x, table) |> as.vector(),
   join_match(x, table),
   #unlist(split(seq(table), table)[as.character(x)],use.names = FALSE),
   check = 'equal'
 )
Unit: microseconds
                 expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq       max neval
     faster(x, table)   23.001   32.751   56.95703   56.400   66.201   222.901   100
 join_match(x, table) 4216.201 4925.302 6616.51401 5572.951 7842.200 21153.402   100
```

Comment: I would like to award this the "most elegant solution", which is also impressively fast.   But will probably give the check mark to the join version, because it is (slightly) faster.  Worth noting though that the memory allocation for this is one third that of the `join_match` answer, so if memory rather than speed were my bottleneck, I would use this solution.

Comment: For my current use case, yes it is a sorted vector with n repetitions.  But the values are not contiguous sequences.  A faster solution that uses these constraints would certainly be great.

Comment: @dww check the edit

Comment: @dww Note that if `x` has alot of repetitions within it, you rather only match the unique values and the extract for the specific x values. ie instead of doing `match(c(2,2,2,2,2), table)` just `match(2,table)` then index accordingly

Answer (score 9):

Should be faster as a join. This is >100x faster.

```
library(dplyr)
join_match = function(x, table) {
  t <- data.frame(table, index = 1:length(table))
  xt <- data.frame(x, index = 1:length(x))
  t |>
    left_join(xt, join_by(table == x), relationship = 'many-to-many') |>
    arrange(index.y) %>%
    filter(!is.na(index.y)) %>%
    pull(index.x)
}
```

Same output, 100-200x as fast, and ~3x as fast as the base R suggestion from @Onyambu (note: that approach has since updated to be similar speed, and a data.table solution is even faster. Using duckdb, or arrow, or collapse to do the join might be faster still. But my observation remains that you can get dramatic speed improvements + legibility by thinking of this as a join):

```
set.seed(42)
table = rep(1:1e5, each=10)
x = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
bench::mark(
  mymatch(x, table) |> as.vector(),
  join_match(x, table),
  unlist(split(seq(table), table)[as.character(x)],use.names = FALSE),
  check = TRUE
)

# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression                                                                min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
  <bch:expr>                                                           <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 as.vector(mymatch(x, table))                                            13.8s    13.8s    0.0727    14.9GB     2.83     1    39      13.8s <int> 
2 join_match(x, table)                                                   48.7ms   62.2ms   13.8       88.8MB     3.95     7     2    506.3ms <int> 
3 unlist(split(seq(table), table)[as.character(x)], use.names = FALSE)  183.6ms  184.5ms    5.31      29.8MB     0        3     0    564.9ms <int>
```

Comment: `mymatch` was producing a matrix. If ok to flatten that to a vector, the output matches my function.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe data.table would be an option? If you have relatively large table/vector you might see an improvement in speed, especially if you go with something along the lines of Jon Spring's "join" approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday, week,
#>     yday, year
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose
library(microbenchmark)

onyambu_faster <- function(x, table){
  a <- rle(table)
  n <- length(a$lengths)
  idx <- match(x, a$values, 0)
  sequence(a$lengths[idx], cumsum(c(1,a$lengths[-n]))[idx])
}

jon_spring_join_match = function(x, table) {
  t <- data.frame(table, index = 1:length(table))
  xt <- data.frame(x, index = 1:length(x))
  t |>
    left_join(xt, join_by(table == x), relationship = 'many-to-many') |>
    arrange(index.y) %>%
    filter(!is.na(index.y)) %>%
    pull(index.x)
}

jared_mamrot_dt <- function(x, table){
  table_dt <- data.table(table, index = 1:length(table))
  x_dt <- data.table(x, index = 1:length(x))
  return(na.omit(table_dt[x_dt, on = .(table == x)][,index]))
}

table = rep(1:1e5, each=10)
x = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)

all.equal(onyambu_faster(x, table), jared_mamrot_dt(x, table))
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(jon_spring_join_match(x, table), jared_mamrot_dt(x, table))
#> [1] TRUE

res <- microbenchmark(onyambu_faster(x, table),
                      jon_spring_join_match(x, table),
                      jared_mamrot_dt(x, table),
                      times = 10)
res
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                             expr       min       lq      mean   median
#>         onyambu_faster(x, table) 38.196317 45.08884  65.22651 52.40748
#>  jon_spring_join_match(x, table) 48.697968 74.54407 105.79551 83.11473
#>        jared_mamrot_dt(x, table)  9.441176 11.34315  12.99648 11.76324
#>         uq       max neval cld
#>   64.88688 129.38505    10 a  
#>  131.50681 221.16477    10  b 
#>   14.05289  21.84779    10   c
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Now I’m curious if duckdb, arrow, or collapse might be even faster…

Answer (score 6):

Using the data in the question this is twice as fast based on the median time on my machine.

```
table = rep(1:5, each=3)
x = c(2, 5, 2, 6)

mymatch = function(x, table) {
  matches = sapply(x, \(xx) which(table %in% xx)) 
  unlist(matches)
}

outer_match <- function(x, table) {
  z1 <- outer(table, x, "==") 
  z2 <- z1 * row(z1)
  z2[z2 != 0]
}

outer_match(x, table)
## [1]  4  5  6 13 14 15  4  5  6

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
 mymatch(x, table),
 outer_match(x, table)
)
## Unit: microseconds
##                   expr  min    lq    mean median   uq    max neval cld
##      mymatch(x, table) 77.0 79.15 166.696  82.75 84.3 8384.9   100   a
##  outer_match(x, table) 35.1 36.75 115.783  41.95 43.1 7410.1   100   a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run `outer` + `row` (short code but might be not that efficient, due to `outer`), e.g.,

```
> row(d <- outer(table, x, `==`))[d]
[1]  4  5  6 13 14 15  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values being matched are integers, then you can use them as index values in a list containing the index values you want (as long as the max integer isn't so big that the list exceeds your RAM capacity).

```
# Process the table vector every time
anjama_list <- function(x, table) {
  l = vector("list", max(table))
  
  i = 0
  for (val in table) {
    i = i + 1
    l[[val]] = c(l[[val]], i)
  }
  
  return(unlist(l[x]))
}
```

Now, this isn't as fast as other solutions mentioned here, but since you are reusing the table for multiple lookups, we can precalculate the list creation and reuse it across iterations:

```
# If the table vector is being reused, only need to process it once
l = vector("list", max(table))

i = 0
for (val in table) {
  i = i + 1
  l[[val]] = c(l[[val]], i)
}

# Now that the list is created, we can do as many lookups as we want without that cost
anjama_list_cache <- function(x, l) {
  return(unlist(l[x]))
}
```

It turns out the list lookup and unlist part is really cheap:

[image: Figure created using the code from jared_mamrot's answer]

*Figure created using the code from jared_mamrot's answer.*

So, it depends on how many times reusing the same table vector makes up for the initial setup. In terms of memory usage, I think the lookup and unlist should also be pretty efficient (the lookup being basically nothing and the unlist being related to the size of your `x` vector), but I haven't tried profiling them.

Comment: @Onyambu Those inputs produce the same results as your functions. `l[2]` returns `NULL`, but it gets ignored with `unlist()`

Comment: You must have done wrong comparison then. The code you gave is ~10x slower. Growing the list each time is quite heavy on R. probably consider doing the same in C++ then call the function in R. But this method is inefficient

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, creating the list each time is slower, as shown by the second line in the figure. But OP has indicated that the lookup vector is being reused, which means the list only has to be created once for multiple runs. The first line in the figure shows the performance after the list has been created and is about 100x faster. So as long as the list is reused enough times, the initial cost of creating it will be offset

Comment: if that is the case, then you are still doing incorrect comparison. Note that if the table is created once, the `rle` adn the `cumsum` in the function I presented should be done outside the comparison and not within the comparison, just the same way your table creation is outside the comparison.

Comment: @Onyambu What do you want me to do? OP is looking for a fast solution to a problem. I provided a possible solution. And since performance matters, I have to compare the speed somehow.

Comment: I am only pointing out that You only compared half. ie your solution will be slow compared to the rest,  if the same parameters were to be applied to the rest.Your solution is fine, only that the comparison gives a false idea that its fast

Comment: It's not a false representation; it represents the expected performance given a large enough number of iterations. It's no different than when people benchmark queries in an indexed vs unindexed database. Or hash map lookups vs a linear search. Given enough iterations, the upfront cost effectively becomes zero, so it gets ignored.

Comment: Depending on OP's requirements, they might need to consider the upfront cost. But my benchmarks show that. And between the two benchmarks, we can estimate the point where the caching becomes beneficial. About 10 runs starts to match some of the other solutions. 100 runs should be competitive with the fastest alternative. And about 10000 runs should be pretty close to what my cached function shows. Roughly, an order of magnitude increase in lookups should result in an order of magnitude better overall performance.

Comment: If there is an issue with the benchmarks, it's that no one has taken the time to look at scalability as either the `x` or `table` vectors change in size. So unless the benchmark data everyone here used is actually characteristic of OP's real data, we don't know if any of the results would change for OP when applied to their data. Memory consumption/scalability is another thing people haven't benchmarked that could be relevant.